# Get a middle-ish string

Tags: code-golf, string

You are the first engineer in a hot new startup, Lexographical. Our company is making waves by digitizing and indexing all words, real or not. The core of our product... Our secret sauce... Well, that's why we hired you :)

Because we're bleeding edge, we're enforcing the latest standards. Even the latest ones aren't good enough. We need the ones that haven't been made yet. No language in existence is good enough for us, so you need to use Lexo to write your code (funnily enough, it looks identical to your favorite programming language).

**Your mission...**

Given 2 strings of arbitrary length and composition, return a string that is lexicographically between the 2 strings (i.e. `input_a` < `output` < `input_b`). Please use standard lexicographical comparisons.

We want ALL THE STRINGS, so the output doesn't have to resemble either of the inputs (though it might, and that's fine).

Because of legal hot water we're in, we can't actually process inputs longer than 10 characters. The output can be as long as we need it to be.

Inputs will always be printable ASCII characters and may not be in lexicographical order. They are gUaranteed to not be identical strings. Sample inputs and outputs (using Python string comparison):

`Lexo`, `Rules` => `M`

`qwerty`, `qwertyuiop` => `qwertyu`

`"123"`, `"124"` => `"1230"`

Oh yeah, we're running this on very *very* small computers... we're on a tight budget. So the smaller you can make the program, the better!

Comment: Are we guaranteed that the two input strings will be in lexicographical order (ie. is the first input always lexicographically smaller than the second)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Code Golf! This appears to be a fairly solid post, but is missing a couple requirements. You definitely need to specify what will appear as input (I'd recommend printable ASCII), and what  the comparison method used should be (I'd recommend usual lexicographical comparisons). Please note we do have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) where you can post challenges for review before posting to main. Good luck!

Comment: @mathjunkie nope, only that they’re not identical.

Comment: I feel like this challenge can be made trivial by repeatedly appending the input with the lexicographically smallest character (which I assume is a space ' ').

Comment: Yes, it does like this challenge can just be "append a space to the smaller string"

Comment: Since you're looking for a string strictly in between, I guess the two inputs need to be not consecutive in lexicographic order?

Comment: If the two strings are "abc" and "abc " (where there's a space, or whatever the lowest character lexicographically is, at the end of the second string), what should the output be?  There is no string in between them lexicographically.  (Edit: I see this is the same as the last question @xnor asked.)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 8 bytes

Appends a space to the first string.

```
a=>a+' '
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-pn`, 5 bytes

```
᠀᠀⑭^,
```

Probably the only valid answer. Same as the 0 byter but it sorts the stack lexically.

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) and [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki), 0 bytes

This is a port of the Javascript answer, but instead of appending a space to the string, it appends a newline. A `0`-byte Keg program is simply a cat program on the first input, meaning that it takes the first word and prints it, followed by a newline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N/w8EPqkV@VxBpTmpxQA)

Comment: Polyglot with 05AB1E, which does the same.

Comment: Actually, based on the response on the very first comment, I think both answers are invalid, for assuming the first input is always the smaller one in lexicographical order.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it should be a valid answer now.